# Inserting a copy of a tuple into a list

Tags: list, haskell

I'm still new to Haskell, my problem is I have issues with adding a modified copy of data type instance into the list of those instances (don't know if it's not synonym).

Data type name is Task, short Tas.

If a task is fulfilled I need to mark it as fulfilled and if it's repeatable, I need to set next date for it (while keeping it in fulfilled tasks).

My approach is to create a copy of that task, basing on it, but with different ID and date and insert it into the list.

remakeDate serves for returning increased date of Task.

```
fulfilledTaskInList :: [Task] -> Int -> Int -> [Task]
fulfilledTaskInList [ ]    check_ID pk_task = []
fulfilledTaskInList (x:xs) check_ID pk_task = if getId x == check_ID then 
                                        if getRepeatT x /= 0 then let help = remakeTask x pk_task in
                                        (setFulfill x):help:xs
                                        else (setFulfill x):xs
                                      else x: fulfilledTaskInList xs check_ID pk_task  

remakeTask x pk_task = do
                (in_year, in_month, in_day) <- remakeDate (getYear x) (getMonth x) (getDay x) (getRepeatT x)
                (Tas {id_Task = pk_task , name = showName x , descr = showDescr x, day = in_day, month = in_month, year = in_year, hour = getHour x, minute = getMinute x, fulfill = 0, repeatT = getRepeatT x})
```

Error thrown by ghci:

```
Task.hs:94:18:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO b0' with actual type `Task'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      (Tas
         {id_Task = pk_task, name = showName x, descr = showDescr x,
          day = in_day, month = in_month, year = in_year, hour = getHour x,
          minute = getMinute x, fulfill = 0, repeatT = getRepeatT x})
    In the expression:
      do { (in_year, in_month, in_day) <- remakeDate
                                            (getYear x) (getMonth x) (getDay x)
(getRepeatT x);
           (Tas
              {id_Task = pk_task, name = showName x, descr = showDescr x,
               day = in_day, month = in_month, year = in_year, hour = getHour x,

               minute = getMinute x, fulfill = 0, repeatT = getRepeatT x}) }
    In an equation for `remakeTask':
        remakeTask x pk_task
          = do { (in_year, in_month, in_day) <- remakeDate
                                                  (getYear x)
                                                  (getMonth x)
                                                  (getDay x)
                                                  (getRepeatT x);
                 (Tas
                    {id_Task = pk_task, name = showName x, descr = showDescr x,
                     day = in_day, month = in_month, year = in_year, hour = getH
our x,
                     minute = getMinute x, fulfill = 0, repeatT = getRepeatT x})
 }
Failed, modules loaded: Functions.
```

Comment: Can't you reduce your problem to something shorter, more readable?

Comment: I believe I made it more readable. Can't shorten error message and shortened problem as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying that the `do` block in `remakeTask` is producing a `Task` as its last statement, but because it's a `do` block, it should produce a monadic value, in this case `IO something`.

You can add a `return` similar to the one in `plusYear` to fix this specific problem. However in general you seem to be using `IO` when you don't really need to, so you might instead investigate removing the `do` blocks along with the use of `return` and `IO`.

Comment: With return Task.hs:153:56:
    Couldn't match expected type `Task' with actual type `IO Task'
    In the first argument of `(:)', namely `help'
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `help : xs'
    In the expression: (setFulfill x) : help : xs
Failed, modules loaded: Functions.     Don't know how should I remove do. I still want my remakeDate to work. Any help with this one?

Comment: OK, so now you're running into the problem that your other function that calls `remakeTask` doesn't expect it to be in `IO`. Rewriting `remakeTask` not to use `IO` would be the best approach.

Comment: Sorry for beginner questions, but how do I rewrite it that way? If I am using return, doesn't it automatically make my function return IO?

Comment: Yes (except that there are monads other than IO, but don't worry about that for now). But if you don't use return, and you don't use do, and you change `remakeDate` to not use return as well, then you can stop using IO at all in those parts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, I've removed all the returns I had (even in remakeDate method) and it worked.